# If two continuous, integrable functions of two variables differ in a neighborhood, is at least one of the single integral functions different?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity

Say we have two real-valued functions $p$ and $q$ of two variables, $x$ and $y$. They are continuous, with finite integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} p(x,y) dx dy < \infty$, $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} q(x,y) dx dy < \infty$, and they differ at a point, call it $(x_0,y_0)$  -- by continuity, they differ in a neighbourhood of it. Now let's integrate $p$ and $q$ over $x$ and $y$ separately, obtaining:

$p^x = \int_{\mathbb{R}} p(x,y) dy$,

$p^y = \int_{\mathbb{R}} p(x,y) dx$,

$q^x = \int_{\mathbb{R}} q(x,y) dy$,

$q^y = \int_{\mathbb{R}} q(x,y) dx$.

Can we say that at least one of the following two inequalities hold?

$p^{x_0} \neq q^{x_0}$,

$p^{y_0} \neq q^{y_0}$.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Also, I guess $p^x(x_0)$ should mean $p^{x_0}$?

Comment: I am puzzled. Two continuous functions cannot differ at only one point.

Comment: @EthanBolker I read it as differ at least at one point.

Comment: Thanks Severin and Ethan for your comments, I've edited the question. I can't figure out how the integration interacts with the value at $(x_0, y_0)$. Since integration is global I can't see why the single variable functions should still differ at the point. I guess I need to clear up my mind on what happens when integrating.

Comment: Well, they don't have to :)

Comment: Do you have an example in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could say it, but it would be false in general :) Consider the following function
$$ p(x,y) = \begin{cases} \sin(x) \cos(y),& (x,y)\in [0,2\pi] \times [\pi/2, 5\pi/2],\\ 0,& \text{otherwise.} \end{cases} $$
This function is continuous (use that $\sin(0)=0=\sin(2\pi)$ and $\cos(\pi/2)=0=\cos(5\pi/2)$). We also have for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$
$$ \int p(x,y) dx = 0 = \int p(x,y) dy.$$
Now, we can define $q(x,y)= p(x+100, y+100)$ which still would be a continuous function with
$$ \int q(x,y) dx = 0 = \int q(x,y) dy.$$
But there are many points, where $p$ and $q$ differ.

In fact, we could pick $p(x,y)=f(x)g(y)$ as long as $f,g$ are continuous with compact support and $\int f(x) dx=0= \int g(y)dy$, but I like $\sin$ and $\cos$.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I can't wrap my mind around it yet but noticed the condition of zero integral, which I hadn't considered. Do you think it's necessary or is it just to make things simpler?

Comment: I guess it is not really necessary, I just wanted to have an easy example. If you don't like $0$, you can just add another function to both $p$ and $q$.

Comment: I think I see now. We take $f$, $g$ to be continuous, compactly supported, with vanishing integral, $h$ to be any continuous finitely-integrable function of two variables and we define $p(x,y) = f(x)g(y) + h(x,y)$ and $q(x,y) = f(x+n)g(y+n) + h(x,y)$ with $n$ sufficiently large to separate the supports of $f$ and $g$. Thank you @Severin, very illuminating example.

Comment: That is exactly what I meant :) you are welcome.